# Como pegar valores de um ou mais inputs

Tags: javascript

Estou começando a programar com JavaScript e estou com dúvida se consigo pegar os 3 valores do `input`.

O resultado sempre vem `Not A Number (NAN)`

```js
function media(){
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor1'));
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor2'));
    var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor3'));

    var resultado = (a + b + c) / 3;

    alert("A média é : " + resultado);
}
```

```css
        form {
        /* Apenas para centralizar o form na página */
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
        /* Para ver as bordas do formulário */
        padding: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius: 1em;
        }
         label {
        /*Para ter certeza que todas as labels tem o mesmo tamanho e estão propriamente alinhadas */
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Média</title>
</head>

<body>


    <form>
        <h1>Cálculo Média</h1>

        <div class="form-group ml-">
            <label>Valor 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="valor1" class="form-control col-6">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Valor 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="valor2" class="form-control col-6">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label>Valor 3</label>
                <input type="text" id="valor3" class="form-control col-6">
        </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-5 my-3" onclick="media()">Calcular</button>
    </form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa colocar o `value` para pegar o valor do input:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor1').value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor2').value);
var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('valor3').value);
```

Comment: Era só isso mesmo, tinha colocado o .value antes, só que tinha outro erro e acabou não funcionando, e acabei tirando o .value !!  Uso o VScode, quando vou colocar o .value ele não aparece a visualização naquela janela como outras funções do javaScript, como se ela não existisse, as vezes acontece isso em várias partes de código.

Comment: Isso é porque o método `getElementById` retorna um objeto do tipo Node. `value` não é uma propriedade da classe Node, apenas classes que estendem a classe Node como HTMLInputElement possuem a propriedade `value`. Por isso o VSCode não sugere essa propriedade, porque até onde o VSCode sabe, essa propriedade não existe no objeto.

Comment: Então é por isso!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!